# Civicrm5.4-add a cash donation fails after update

Tags: civicontribute

Running on Linx hosted system with latest WP. I just updated from Civi 4.7 to 5.4, now when i try to record a cash donation ('New Contribution') I get a message that the 'site is experiencing technical difficulties'.  Paid events are processed.  This is not even including an email receipt.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check Civi logs to see more details about the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please cancel! I found the problem. sorry to bother

Comment: Good to know you have found the problem ... could you share some details to help anyone else facing the same symptoms?

Comment: The reason I didn't share more is because -I- caused the problem myself (I had created a local mod in price_set processAmount which I overrode the core one with, and hadn't updated the call in contribution.php) - so, rather embarrassed.

Comment: Ah yes - I've done my share of self-inflicted misery too :-)